# Add texture on vuforia example

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, vuforia

I try to add 2d textures on the Vuforia "Image Target part". I try to add a SquareTexture from one of my other project.
So I have that class:

```
package com.vuforia.samples.VuforiaSamples.app.ImageTargets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

/**
 * A two-dimensional square for use as a drawn object in OpenGL ES 2.0.
 */
public class SquareTexture {

    private static int[] textureHandle;

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
                    "attribute vec2 aPosition;\n" +
                    "attribute vec2 aTexPos;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 vTexPos;\n" +
                    "void main() {\n" +
                    "  vTexPos = aTexPos;\n" +
                    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vec4(aPosition.xy, 0.0, 1.0);\n" +
                    //"  gl_Position = vec4(aPosition.xy, 0.0, 1.0);\n" +
                    "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;\n"+
                    "uniform sampler2D uTexture;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 vTexPos;\n" +
                    "void main(void)\n" +
                    "{\n" +
                    //"  gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vec2(vTexPos.y,vTexPos.x));\n" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = vec4( 1,1,0,(vTexPos.x+vTexPos.y)/2.0);\n" +
                    "}";

    private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private final FloatBuffer vertexTextureBuffer;
    private final ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
    private final int mProgram;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mTexturePosHandle;
    private int mColorHandle;
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;


    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 2;

    float squareCoords[] = {

            -1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f,-1.0f,
            -1.0f,-1.0f,
    };

    float squareCoordstexture[] = {


            0.0f, 0.0f, // vertex 3
            0.0f, 1.0f, // vertex 1
            1.0f, 1.0f, // vertex 0
            1.0f, 0.0f, // vertex 2





    }; // top right

    private final short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices

    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

    float color[] = { 0.2f, 0.709803922f, 0.898039216f, 1.0f };

    /**
     * Sets up the drawing object data for use in an OpenGL ES context.
     */
    Context localContext;
    public SquareTexture(Context context) {

        localContext = context;
        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                squareCoords.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);


        ByteBuffer bbt = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                squareCoordstexture.length * 4);
        bbt.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexTextureBuffer = bbt.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexTextureBuffer.put(squareCoordstexture);
        vertexTextureBuffer.position(0);


        // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
                drawOrder.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);

        checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");
        // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
        int vertexShader = loadShader(
                GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = loadShader(
                GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables
        String LogInfo = GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(mProgram);



        checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");


    }








    int frame = 0;
    public  int loadTexture()
    {

        textureHandle = new int[80];



        checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

        for(int i=0;i<80;i++) {
            GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, i);
            int id = localContext.getResources().getIdentifier("ppp" + i, "drawable", localContext.getPackageName());
//            Log.d("loadtexture", id + " vs " + R.drawable.alpha0);
            //final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            //options.inScaled = false;   // No pre-scaling
            // Read in the resource
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(localContext.getResources(), id);

            // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[i]);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, bitmap, 0);

            bitmap.recycle();
        }
      /*  GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, 640, 480,
                0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, IntBuffer.wrap(pixels));*/
//        // since we're using a PNG file with transparency, enable alpha blending.

        checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

//
//
//            // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.



        return textureHandle[0];


    }



    /**
     * Encapsulates the OpenGL ES instructions for drawing this shape.
     *
     * @param mvpMatrix - The Model View Project matrix in which to draw
     * this shape.
     */

    public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {

        // Add program to OpenGL environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle     = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
        //checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");
        mTexturePosHandle   = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTexPos");
        //checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");
        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices

        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                mPositionHandle, 2,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                8, vertexBuffer);

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        //checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");


        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                mTexturePosHandle, 2,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                8, vertexTextureBuffer);

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTexturePosHandle);
        //checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

        // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        //checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
        //checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");



        int uTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uTexture");
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[((frame++)/10)%80]);
        //checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");
        GLES20.glUniform1i(uTexture, 0);
        //checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

        // GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Draw the square


        GLES20.glDrawElements(
                GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
                GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);

        frame++;
    }


    /**
     * Utility method for compiling a OpenGL shader.
     *
     * <p><strong>Note:</strong> When developing shaders, use the checkGlError()
     * method to debug shader coding errors.</p>
     *
     * @param type - Vertex or fragment shader type.
     * @param shaderCode - String containing the shader code.
     * @return - Returns an id for the shader.
     */
    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

        // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);


        return shader;
    }

    /**
     * Utility method for debugging OpenGL calls. Provide the name of the call
     * just after making it:
     *
     * <pre>
     * mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
     * AGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");</pre>
     *
     * If the operation is not successful, the check throws an error.
     *
     * @param glOperation - Name of the OpenGL call to check.
     */
    public static void checkGlError(String glOperation) {
        int error;
        while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.e("SquareTexture", glOperation + ": glError " + error);
            throw new RuntimeException(glOperation + ": glError " + error);
        }
    }

}
```

I add the SquareTexture in onSurfaceCreated function and I draw it when renderFrame from ImageTargetRenderer class is call.

There is no error but the texture just don't appear. In my other project the same class work properly but here I can see the square textured.

Edit : Thank you, it was indded a problem of scale but now I have an other trouble. The image is not show properly, there are transparency dot on the image.

[image]

Comment: I strongly suggest you open a new question for other issues, since this issue was resolved - it might be very difficult for other people having issues to track it and use it this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say you have no gl errors, and since you did not mention it, I guess this class is from a project without Vuforia, my first suspect would be the transformations - it is probably drawn, but out of screen or too little. Check if the way you draw this fits the coordinate system of your Vuforia project, start with the scaling of the squar - try to make it very big and see if it is drawn.

Comment: This is the reason why I made in the shader that line, ""  gl_Position = vec4(aPosition.xy, 0.0, 1.0);\n" "to avoid problem of scaling.  I think that should avoid the scale problem?

Comment: Hmmm, no, I do not think so... Try scaling it up and see

Comment: how could I scale it up?

Comment: You have this in the Vuforia sample - I do not know what you are using exactly, but search the code for "scale"